# Java Wireless module development

Tags: java, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I am by no means a Java expert (not really intermediate either) but i can write enough to get me by. At work we are looking a Cinterion TC65 wireless module which runs embedded Java with a 2G sim card for network connections. I have never done Java mobile dev so the whole startApp(), pauseApp(), destryApp() is throwing me slightly. What i need to know is if its possible to include normal Java code, ie. Mysql Connections, HTTP connections? Or does it all have to be done over AT commands? I need some Java buffs to help me out on this one :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are various UI framework available for J2ME app development

- lcdui
- lwuit
- kuix

If you want simple UI then go for *lcdui* , It also comes with Netbeans designer so you don;t need to much worry about designing form and flow of application.

You can't have mysql connection directly from j2me application, for that you need to port your webservices accessing your DB and you can call your webservices. you can also make URLConnections.

Comment: Excellent, so if i wrote a PHP script on my webserver which the Java could send data over GET and then let the PHP do the mysql? That the idea?

Comment: yes that can be done, but I would suggest to go for webservice approch , it is better

Comment: By webservice what exactly do you mean? (in this context)

Comment: Jeeez, i may be better sticking to PHP! Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

The TC65 and later modules such as TC65i, BGS5, EHS6, ELS61-E all run Java ME 3.2 so you can write normal Java. But you do have to write with a reduced J2ME 3.2 feature set, you cannot use newer features of Java 7 or 8 for example.

The two development environments you can use are Eclipse Juno and Netbeans 7. These come supplied on an installation "CDROM" download.

These two links show how to get started with either Eclipse or Netbeans on a current module such as BGS5 or EHS6. The simple tutorial re-uses an beginner's example from a Java text book:

Eclipse - https://developer.gemalto.com/tutorial/starting-out-java-me-volcano-robot-project-eclipse-juno

Netbeans - https://developer.gemalto.com/tutorial/starting-out-java-me-volcano-robot-project-netbeans-72

There are further examples of using HTTP connections on the developer website:

```
String connProfile = "bearer_type=gprs;access_point=internet;username=;password=";
http = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url + ";" + connProfile);
```

You can also use the module's Internet Services via AT Commands, but there is no need as most functions have Java APIs associated with them.